# Knowledge search not returning articles created after Winter 15

Tags: knowledge

We have installed the public knowledge app in sandbox. After Winter 15, articles created after winter 15 are not showing up in the search. Articles created before, are being returned. has anyone experienced this issue ?

I have found the SOSL query and run it and while I can find records created before in the KnowledgeArticleVersion object using the article number, I cannot find the articles newly created.

I can run a SOQL query and it returns ArticleNumber 1352 but SOSL query with same criteria  returns no records for 1352. It does return record for 1332 that was created before Winter 15.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to [this](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XciAAE) which is a known issue with Winter15.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce support investigated and did fix it by re-indexing.  Just wanted to post this in case anyone else experienced this same issue.